# How many test cases needed to perform MCDC coverage on (A || B)

Tags: matlab, embedded, simulink

I studied that the number of test case should come out to be **n+1**,
where **n** is the number of variables.

Comment: You have given an answer, so why are you asking.  If you doubt your own answer, you should explain why.  If you believe it, you should provide your reasoning.  You might also elaborate the question by explaining what MCDC coverage is (or a link) - it is likely that many who have never come across the term (me) could nonetheless answer if it is just a matter of mathematics.

Comment: I am struggling to see why this is tagged [embedded].  I don't think the ultimate target platform affects the answer.

Comment: If you are looking for an explanation of why n+1 is correct, you should ask that.

Answer (score 0):

When A is true, B is not evaluated so does not affect the outcome, so all decisions with A=true are one test case.  When A is false both states of B affect the outcome, so in total it requires three test cases.

Now whether that can be generalised to n+1 is not really proven by the above, but that is not what you have asked - you merely stated that.  However, if you consider the case where B represents a sub-expression C||D, requiring three rest cases, then the test where A is true, that is four test cases (i.e. n+1).

So to generalise for any expression:

```
<condition>||<decision>
```

the number of test cases is:

```
1 + test_cases(<decision>)
```